# reflection in the micro world.

Tags: visible-light

I have a hypothetical question in my mind. Suppose I have a single photon and an atom and I throw the photon towards the atom. So if the photon gets reflected, from where is it likely to do so?? From the nucleus or the orbiting electrons?

Comment: Mostly, it's the electron cloud that is responsible for reflection, but it does depend on the wave length of the photon.

Answer (score 0):

The type of scattering that you're talking about, i.e. scattering of light from single atoms or molecules, is known as [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering). It's this scattering from air molecules that makes the sky blue.

The mathematics that describes Rayleigh scattering is quite involved - the Wikipedia article provides all the details if you're curious. In brief the oscillating electric field of the light induces an oscillating dipole in the atom and this oscillating dipole scatters the incident light.

The magnitude of the induced dipole, and hence the scattering, depends on the [polarisibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizability) of the atom, and this is largely a function of the electron density. So in this sense it is the electrons that scatter the light. However it wouldn't be a dipole without the positive nucleus to act as the positive end of the dipole, so you can't really say it's just the electrons doing the scattering.